# Is it possible to tell if a CNPhoneNumber in the iOS SDK is connected to iMessage?

Tags: ios

iPhones (excuse me, iPhone phones) know whether a number is connected to iMessage - they turn the number blue and send messages on the iMessage system.

Is it possible to get only a user's iMessage numbers? This would be quite useful for an invitation system of an iOS only app.